# How do I block and capture mouse click events in X11?

Tags: c++, linux, callback, x11, color-picker

I am looking to block mouse click events and bring them into my own callback hook based on X11 as the only dependency. I'm trying to make an eyedropper color picker, and I want to avoid unfocusing the window that the color picker is hosted in, even when I click outside of it. So, I would like to get feedback for the fact that the user clicked, and then block the event going to the rest of the apps or the code that changes window focus.

I also need to be able to run code based on the mouse click that I'm trying to block. So when the click is blocked, it should also run a callback function so I can send the color back to my code.

I am using C++ and making the Linux part of my app.
I cannot use sudo or being root for this implementation, as this is a simple color picker, which should not be requiring root.

I've looked at `XGrabPointer`, but it doesn't seem to do what I want, unless I am misunderstanding the code.